# mysql as data source in VS 2013 for web express edition

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2013, database-connection

On [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/visual-studio/en/visual-studio-install.html) it is mentioned

> MySQL for Visual Studio does not support Express versions of Microsoft
>   development products, including the Visual Studio and the Microsoft
>   Visual Web Developer. To use MySQL Connector/Net with an Express
>   versions of Microsoft development products, use MySQL Connector/Net
>   6.7.4 or later, without installing the MySQL for Visual Studio.

but when I do the same, I do not get MySql as datasource in data connection
can any one help?

Comment: now able to fetch data from vs2013 web express, I just add in Add reference>>extention>>MySql.data and made changes in connectionstring in web.config., now it is working as i run select query, it is fetching data